# Delete duplicate entry in table PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I try to create a pg/plsql script to delete double entry in an TABLE and report in another row if the user fav another user, this is the code :

```
\timing on
DO $$
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        i INT := 1;
        maxID INT;
    BEGIN
        CREATE TEMP TABLE query ("id" SERIAL, "idUser1" INT, "idUser2" INT, "favorite" BOOLEAN);
        
        INSERT INTO query FROM "WU_MatchingUsers" WHERE "id" IN (SELECT "id" FROM (SELECT "id", ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY "IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2" ORDER BY "id" DESC) AS row_num FROM "WU_MatchingUsers") t WHERE t.row_num >1), "UserAFavoriteTag"; 
        
        SELECT INTO maxID MAX("id") FROM query;
        
        WHILE i < maxID LOOP
            IF SELECT "favorite" FROM query WHERE "id" = i; THEN
                SELECT * FROM "WU_MatchingUsers" WHERE "id" IN (SELECT "id" FROM (SELECT "id", ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY "IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2" ORDER BY "id" DESC) AS row_num FROM "WU_MatchingUsers") t WHERE t.row_num >1) WHERE "IDWU_User1" = SELECT "idUser1" FROM query AND "IDWU_User2" = SELECT "idUser2" FROM query;
                ELSE
                    RAISE NOTICE "Not IF";
            END IF;
        DELETE FROM "WU_MatchingUsers" WHERE "id" IN (SELECT "id" FROM (SELECT "id", ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY "IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2" ORDER BY "id" DESC) AS row_num FROM "WU_MatchingUsers") t WHERE t.row_num >1), "UserAFavoriteTag"; 
    END;
END $$;
\timing off
```

and here is the error that psql return :

```
psql:duplicateDeleter.sql:22: ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « FROM »
LIGNE 9 :         INSERT INTO query FROM "WU_MatchingUsers" WHERE "id"...
```

Comment: I changed what you said and I still have the same error

Comment: I have corrected your syntax errors [check here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f3e6eafefac7784961976d8540ef7b39). But I am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve. So logic part can not be assured. If you update your detailed requirement with table structure and sample data by editing the question, then it will be good to get the correct query because your query is having so many junk things.